# Add Element to Multidimensional Array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to figure this out but keep getting confused with code examples.

How can I add a single element to the array below.

```
$datafields = array(
    "helpdesk_ticket" => array(
        "subject" => $subject,
        "description" => $notes,
        "email" => "joe@email.net",
        "priority" => $priority2,
        "ticket_type" => $type,
        "viewed" => $viewed
    )
);
```

So for instance I want to add:

```
"status" => $status
```

Comment: Thanks Ghost I had something like that before but was doing something weird with the value which is why it probably didnt work.

Comment: @Ghost You really show post that as an answer so StackOverflow works. I don't want to take away your earned reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a simple array assignment.

```
$datafields['helpdesk_ticket']['status'] = $status;
```

For more info read the manual about [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)